# TextToSplit does not exist in current context

Tags: c#

Am giving to 2 variables the data type as string and integer.

However C# is saying that they don't exist.

Have tried something as object TexttoSplit { get; private set; } but still doesn't run correctly.

Any help would be much appreciated!

```
private static List<string> SplitTextByLengthEngine(string Texttosplit, int MaxLineLength)
{

    List<string> RetVal = new List<string>();
    MaxLineLength = Math.Min(MaxLineLength, TexttoSplit.Length);

    int LastIndex = TexttoSplit.Substring(0, Math.Min((MaxLineLength + 1), TextToSplit.Length)).LastIndexOf(" ");
    if (((TextToSplit.Length <= MaxLineLength)
    || (LastIndex == -1)))
    {
        RetVal.Add(TexttoSplit.Substring(0, MaxLineLength));
        string RemainingText = TexttoSplit.SubString(MaxLineLength, (TextToSplit.Length - MaxLineLength)).Trim();
    }
    if ((RemainingText.Length > 0))
    {
        RetVal.AddRange(SplitTextByLengthEngine(RemainingText, MaxLineLength));
    }
    else
    {
        // Track backwards to find previous non-space character
        int Index = (LastIndex - 1);
        while (((Index >= 0)
        && (TextToSplit.SubString(Index, 1) == " ")))
        {
            Index--;
        }

        if ((Index >= 0))
        {
            RetVal.Add(TextToSplit.SubString(0, (Index + 1)));
            string RemainingText = TexttoSplit.SubString((Index + 1), (TextToSplit.Length
            - (Index + 1))).Trim();
        }
        if ((RemainingText.Length > 0))
        {
            RetVal.AddRange(SplitTextByLengthEngine(RemainingText, MaxLineLength));

        }
        return RetVal;
    }

}
```

Comment: your parameter is Texttosplit, not TexttoSplit - which line is the error on and exactly what is the error

Comment: `string Texttosplit`; `if (((TextToSplit ... ` . C# is case sensitive, make sure they have the same name.

Comment: What is the purpose of `SplitTextByLengthEngine` routine, please? Could you provide *some examples* with initial strings, `MaxLineLength` and the desired outcomes?

Comment: Incidentally, C# uses `camelCase` by convention - if you name your variable `textToSplit`, IDEs are likely to provide you with better formatting that makes your development easier.

Answer (score 3):

The method argument is called `Texttosplit`

In the method body you refer to `TextToSplit`

Note the difference in upper/lowercase

Comment: Am trying to convert Vb to C#.